# Deploying .ipa To End Users

Tags: ipa

I need to create a permanent link to share .ipa to end users. I know only two ways to do:

1. diawi: but the link that is generated isn't permanent
2. itms-service: `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.example.com/manifest.plist`
   but in the server i do not have a secure certificate so https links are not allowed.

Can anybody gives me any hint or any other way what i can do?

Comment: Can you use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @mikep can you give me a workaround how this can be done?

Comment: Which webserver are you using and do you have access?

Comment: @mikep i have a windows server 2008 R2 and webserver IIs version 7.5

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=ws.10).aspx is pretty short.  Let me know if you have problems.

Comment: @mikep i did those steps, but i am not clear for something. Now i am supposed to be able to visit my website with https, bc i am not able yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147240/discussion-between-belka-and-mikep).

Comment: OK, start the chat.